# How to add browserify as a dependency of your node.js application?

Tags: node.js, npm

My node.js application depends on the fact browserify is available on the command line, as it uses it on a shell script. How can I make sure it is available on the application without having to require my client to install it manually via `npm install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not giving too much context, I'm assuming that your external dependencies are located in `./node_modules` in your app's directory.

In that case, just install `browserify` as an extra (local) dependency, which will make it available as `./node_modules/.bin/browserify`. That's also how you can refer to it from your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

An even better option is to install browserify as follows:

`npm install --save browserify`

This not only installs browserify for you, but also adds it as a dependency to your dependencies in your `package.json` file.

Now when someone installs your module i.e. via `npm install yourmodule`, browserify will be installed automatically into its `./node_modules`.

This of course works for any module you depend on, not only browserify.